# How regex match exact 3 numbers

Tags: regex, go

I want true for these cases:

```
.123
.000
.999
```

And want false for these cases:

```
123
a123
.123a
.1234
a.123
```

This is my current regex:

```
match, _ := regexp.MatchString("[.]{1}[0-9]{3}", ".123a")
fmt.Println(match)
```

But this pattern doesn't return `false` for:

```
.123a
.1234
a.123
```

What is the correct regex?

Comment: Recommend using backticks to put literal strings `  ` for regex definitions than `'..'` or `".."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, try restricting the match with `^[.]{1}[0-9]{3}$`

[See online demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZ8AI6/1)

Comment: Didn't the OP say that it *cannot* return `false` those cases?

Comment: @npinti I assumed language barriers here because he technically repeated himself regarding the last three matches saying he "want false" but "cannot return false"

Answer (score 2):

The pattern is as simple as:

```
^\.\d{3}$
```

Same as:

```
^\.[0-9]{3}$
```

Which is:

```
^     // from the beginning
\.    // a single dot
\d{3} // a digit (exactly 3 times)
$     // until the end of the string
```

You have to escape the `\` symbol though so: `^\\.\\d{3}$`

[Regexp Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IkLhWO/1). [Go Demo](https://play.golang.org/p/dYFM-ZvApH8).